# Problem with traffic source and virtual events. Google Tag manager Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having some troubles with GTM and iframe.

My website has a button that redirects to Shore for booking. On mobile a new tag opens. 
I can see at Content on Google Analytics:

1. /
2. /bookings/my-website/services?layout=nolayout&locale=es&origin=nolayout&theme_color=1f1f1f
3. /virtual/select-service
4. /virtual/booking-success

The problem is that I loose the medium. At the begining is Organic/cpc...
But on step 2 it creates a new sesion (none)/(direct). It's false.

Could you help me keep the medium on the /virtual/{{Event}}?

### My GTM configuration is:

**Trigger:**

- Custom Event
- Event name: .*
- Some custom events: Event -> matches RegEx -> (select)|(success)|(booking)

**Tag config:**

- Track Type: Page View
- Enable overriding settings on this tag (checked)
- Fields to Set:

  - Field name: Page   ->   value:  virtual/{{Event}}.
- Tag firing options:Once per page

It's strange because medium is ok when the reservation is through Facebook or Instagram. It just fails on the website.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely an issue with the changing of domains as users navigate to the widget. Unless cross-domain tracking is specifically set up, when a user visits *Site A* and then *Site B*, and both sites have the same Google Analytics (or GA through GTM) tag, the visit to *Site B* will record a source/medium of either `direct/none` or `{Site A}/Referral`, depending on your [referral exclusion](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830) setup. This is regardless of the source/medium was recorded for the visit to *Site A*.

In your scenario, hit 1 (`/`) is your own domain, and then (I'm guessing) hits 2-4 are on Shore's domain (probably `connect.shore.com` according to the [help page](https://shorehelpcenter.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022207434-How-Can-I-Set-Up-Google-Analytics-Tracking-for-My-Booking-Page-)).

To remedy this, you need to setup cross-domain tracking. The official guide for GA through GTM is [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164469), but another excellent resource is [Simo Ahava's blog](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/troubleshooting-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-analytics/). Note that cross-domain linking needs to be setup with every page in the funnel. This means if you are using GTM to deploy GA for the booking virtual pageviews, but are using the direct embed code to put GA on your own site (step 1), with `analytics.js`, then you need to follow [the guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342) to enable it there.